# Difference between "If i see it,i will tell you." and "If i saw it, i would tell you."

Tags: grammar, tense

1. Is "If I see it, I will tell you." the declarative mood, and "If I saw it, I would tell you." the subjunctive mood?
2. Dose "I see" show more probability of seeing it than "I saw"?
3. Could you distinguish "If I saw it, I would tell you." is the subjunctive mood in the present or the indicative mood in the past without context?

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly:

"If I see it, I'll tell you" suggests that there is a realistic possibility in reality of me seeing whatever 'it' is. On the other hand, "If I saw it, I would tell you" is a general statement about what I would do in the hypothetical situation that I saw it.

(See https://www.studypro.eu/english-grammar/1st-and-2nd-conditionals.html, for example. There are lots of other resources on this topic on the internet.)